# How to convert UTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app (in Rubymotion).
I got incoming dates from an API that I would like to parse and save locally.

This is the dateformat:

```
2014-08-18T20:51:00.000+02:00
```

I try to parse it with this code but I only get *nil* back (I tried with and without setting timezone):

```
df = NSDateFormatter.alloc.init
df.setTimeZone(NSTimeZone.timeZoneWithAbbreviation("UTC"))
df.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")

date = df.dateFromString(date)
```

Comment: Convert UTC to what? This question title is very ambiguous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```